# Cypress: Select only one type of elements but almost with the same class as the rest of the elements

Tags: javascript, class, select, cypress

Please In one container I have 3 different types of buttons. How do I select those buttons, which match the exact class? Because when I go for cy.get('.MuiButtonBase-root.MuiIconButton-root.MuiPickersDay-day'), it will select all the buttons, because the two other types contain the same class as well. Unfortunately there is no ID to better catch the element. Thank you.

```
<button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day" type="button">
<button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" type="button">
<button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled MuiPickersDay-hidden" type="button">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to select all buttons that are not disabled or hidden?

Take a look at [jQuery :not() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), you can use it like this

```js
cy.get('.MuiPickersDay-day:not(.MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled):not(.MuiPickersDay-hidden)')
```

---

Alternatively you can apply a filter function to the elements

```js
cy.get('.MuiPickersDay-day')
  .filter((index, el) => {
    return !el.classList.contains('MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled') &&
           !el.classList.contains('MuiPickersDay-hidden')
  })
```

---

Testing with

```html
<container>
  <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day" type="button"></button>
  <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" type="button"></button>
  <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled MuiPickersDay-hidden" type="button"></button>
</container>

<container>
  <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day" type="button"></button>
  <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled" type="button"></button>
  <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled MuiPickersDay-hidden" type="button"></button>
</container>
```

```js
it('finds all buttons not type disabled or hidden', () => {

  cy.get('.MuiPickersDay-day:not(.MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled):not(.MuiPickersDay-hidden)')
    .should('have.length', 2)                                       // passes

  cy.get('.MuiPickersDay-day')
    .filter((index, el) => {
      return !el.classList.contains('MuiPickersDay-dayDisabled') &&
             !el.classList.contains('MuiPickersDay-hidden')
    })
    .should('have.length', 2)                                       // passes
})
```

Comment: This is it `:not()` is perfect, thank you

Comment: Is there some command to include also other class? like :and() or :include()

Comment: Well `and` is exactly as you have in your question, just `.thisclass.thatclass`. `include` would need to use the filter, just about anything can be done in a filter if you know some intermediate javascript. So to `include` a partial string, say "pickers", somewhere in the class list `return [...el.classList].some(class => class.includes("pickers");`

Comment: May need to double-check that last one.

Answer (score 1):

1.You can use the `eq()` command to select the first or second or third.

```
//Clicks first button
cy.get('.MuiButtonBase-root.MuiIconButton-root.MuiPickersDay-day').eq(1).click() 

//Clicks second button
cy.get('.MuiButtonBase-root.MuiIconButton-root.MuiPickersDay-day').eq(2).click() 

//Clicks third button
cy.get('.MuiButtonBase-root.MuiIconButton-root.MuiPickersDay-day').eq(3).click()
```

2.Or, If you have unique Text for these three elements, you can use `contains()` as well to find the unique element and then click it -

```
cy.contains('some text').cilck()
```

For example, if they are numbers you can use:

```
cy.contains('1').cilck()
```

3.To select all buttons in one go you can use `click({multiple: true})`

```
cy.get('.MuiButtonBase-root.MuiIconButton-root.MuiPickersDay-day').click({multiple: true})
```

4.Or, you can use `each()` as well to iterate over all the elements and click all of them:

```
cy.get('.MuiButtonBase-root.MuiIconButton-root.MuiPickersDay-day').each(($ele) => {
    cy.wrap($ele).click()
})
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for help, but I would like to select all the buttons <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersDay-day" type="button">, not just the first one of that type. And of course all the other buttons which have a class on top of the first type would not be selected. Eq would select just the first one, not all of them. These are not just 3 buttons. But 3 types of buttons. Every type can have 10buttons for example and I want to select all of them for each type at once.